# Import Excel to Microsoft SQL getting slow

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I have a software in C# that copies all Excel files in a folder (.xls only - not xlsx) to a Microsoft SQL database using some criterias.

It maps what it needs to import using Excel named ranges. It does not use row/column references.
Based on the named range, the program look on a table, see in which table that info should go and insert the information.

My problem:
Excel files are really big, so it take 1 minute to import one file. If I put 10 files, it take one minute to import each one.

But if I put 100 files to import in sequence, it starts taking 1 minute, but the time keeps getting bigger. Sometimes it take 20 minutes to import a single file.

I know this is very little information, but I am hopping you can give some tips to try to find out what is making the program slow down that much.

Comment: Show us the _codez_!

Comment: There is no way anyone can help with that description. You need to post some code! Clearly there is some kind of 'leakage' in it. Have you checked to see if the process memory is increasing or if CPU is maxed out? Have you identified which are the lines taking the most time?

Comment: I know it's hard. I'll try to post some code.
I'll try to look those thing you said, that maybe help my find the problem also.

I am not an expert on C#. We hired a company to write this code for us, but it was a while ago so now we have to maintain the software.

I don't know what would be the important to post here, because it is a really long code.